# Middleman with vue-router loading 'Page Not Found' on page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, middleman, middleman-4

I'm building a website that uses Middleman (Ruby) on the backend and VueJS on the front end, along with vue-router to handle routing. In my vue-router index, I'm loading the Video component on /chapter/:id as you can see here:

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: 'chapter',
    path: '/chapter/:id',
    component: Video,
    props: true
  },
]
```

Everything is working as expected when you click on a `<router-link>` - but when you reload the page (for example: /chapter/2) it loads 'File Not Found' from Middleman.

Is there something in Middleman to disable routing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configure your backend to return `index.html` when the requested address is `chapter/:id`, or, whenever it's not an address in your backend api list.

When we use a single-page-app built with vue, we are always in `index.html`, which has a `app.js` or something running all along, and when the route changes, the script detects that and change the page content, but we never left `index.html`. So when we reload the page, the browser requests a document/html from the server, when the html arrives with the js script inside it, the script runs, determines what to show due to the address/route, and we are up and going fine.

So in your case, just need to fix the "make sure the browser gets the html file when visiting `/chapter/:id`" part.